# Android Kotlin: if i don't select images to save on the app, the app do not work

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

On my app, users can save some notes with image. But, users can not save their notes without image. Thus image is compulsory to save their data. But ı want to change it. I want to allow them to save their note without image. How can ı do this ? This is my saveclcikbutton codes;

```
class TakeNotesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var selectedPicture: Uri? = null
    var selectedBitmap: Bitmap? = null
    private lateinit var db: FirebaseFirestore
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_notes)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    }


    fun putPictureClick(view: View) {

        val popupMenu = PopupMenu(this, view)
        val inflater = popupMenu.menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.secondmenu, popupMenu.menu)
        popupMenu.show()

        popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener {

            if (it.itemId == R.id.galleryImage) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this,
                        android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this,
                        arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                        1
                    )

                } else {
                    val intentToGallery =
                        Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
                    startActivityForResult(intentToGallery, 2)
                }

            }

            if (it.itemId == R.id.capturePhoto) {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        this,
                        android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                    ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this,
                        arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA),
                        10
                    )

                } else {

                    openCamera()

                }

            }

            if (it.itemId == R.id.cancel) {

                Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Canceled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            }

            true

        }

    }

    fun openCamera() {

        val values = ContentValues()
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture")
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From the Camera")
        selectedPicture =
            contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values)

        // Camera Intent

        val cameraIntent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, selectedPicture)
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 20)


    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {

            if (grantResults.size > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                val intentToGallery =
                    Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
                startActivityForResult(intentToGallery, 2)
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == 10) {

            if (grantResults.size > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                openCamera()

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }

        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {

            selectedPicture = data.data

            try {

                if (selectedPicture != null) {

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 28) {
                        val source =
                            ImageDecoder.createSource(this.contentResolver, selectedPicture!!)
                        selectedBitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
                        imageButton.setImageBitmap(selectedBitmap)


                    } else {

                        selectedBitmap =
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver, selectedPicture)
                        imageButton.setImageBitmap(selectedBitmap)
                    }

                }

            } catch (e: Exception) {

            }

        }

        //called when image was captured from camera intent

        if (requestCode == 20 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            imageButton.setImageURI(selectedPicture)
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
fun saveClick(view: View) {

    //UUID -> Image Name

    val uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
    val imageName = "$uuid.jpg"


    val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
    val reference = storage.reference
    val imagesReference = reference.child("images").child(imageName)

    if (selectedPicture != null) {

        imagesReference.putFile(selectedPicture!!).addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->

            // take the picture link to save the database

            val uploadedPictureReference =
                FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("images").child(imageName)
            uploadedPictureReference.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
                val downloadUrl = uri.toString()
                println(downloadUrl)

                val noteMap = hashMapOf<String, Any>()
                noteMap.put("downloadUrl", downloadUrl)
                noteMap.put("userEmail", auth.currentUser!!.email.toString())
                noteMap.put("noteTitle", titleText.text.toString())
                noteMap.put("yourNote", noteText.text.toString())
                noteMap.put("date", Timestamp.now())

                db.collection("Notes").add(noteMap).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isComplete && task.isSuccessful) {

                        finish()
                    }


                }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->

                    Toast.makeText(
                        applicationContext,
                        exception.localizedMessage?.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()

                }

            }

        }

    }


}
```

}

I also try to add on saveClick fun the codes below but did not work. What should I do ?

```
fun saveClick(view: View) {

    //UUID -> Image Name

    val uuid = UUID.randomUUID()
    val imageName = "$uuid.jpg"


    val storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance()
    val reference = storage.reference
    val imagesReference = reference.child("images").child(imageName)

    if (selectedPicture != null) {

        imagesReference.putFile(selectedPicture!!).addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->

            // take the picture link to save the database

            val uploadedPictureReference =
                FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("images").child(imageName)
            uploadedPictureReference.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
                val downloadUrl = uri.toString()
                println(downloadUrl)

                val noteMap = hashMapOf<String, Any>()
                noteMap.put("downloadUrl", downloadUrl)
                noteMap.put("userEmail", auth.currentUser!!.email.toString())
                noteMap.put("noteTitle", titleText.text.toString())
                noteMap.put("yourNote", noteText.text.toString())
                noteMap.put("date", Timestamp.now())

                db.collection("Notes").add(noteMap).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isComplete && task.isSuccessful) {

                        finish()
                    }


                }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->

                    Toast.makeText(
                        applicationContext,
                        exception.localizedMessage?.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    ).show()

                }
            }
        }
    }else {
        val noteMap = hashMapOf<String, Any>()
        noteMap.put("userEmail", auth.currentUser!!.email.toString())
        noteMap.put("noteTitle", titleText.text.toString())
        noteMap.put("yourNote", noteText.text.toString())
        noteMap.put("date", Timestamp.now())

        db.collection("Notes").add(noteMap).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isComplete && task.isSuccessful) {

                finish()
            }


        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So what "did not work"? Did you get an error?

Comment: There is no error but application closed and ı had to delete all database to reopen again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all your logic is basically wrapped up in that `putFile` success callback, which requires an image to be successfully stored and retrieved (?) before anything will be added to the database.

You need to break that logic up, so you can only run the parts you want to - like just running the database update part if you don't have an image, or running that part later once your image is successfully handled.

So really, you need a "store in database" function to handle the final writing - call that directly if you don't have an image, call it in the success callbacks if you do. I'm just going to pseudocode this but:

```
saveData(noteMap: Map) {
    add note to DB
}

saveClick() {
    create noteMap with basic, non-image details (email, title etc)
    if image is null, call saveData(noteMap)
    else do the image stuff:
        onSuccess:
            add the downloadUrl to noteMap
            call saveData(noteMap)
}
```

I see you've made an edit with an else branch which creates the map sans url and writes it - you're basically almost there, just make it a function instead, and pass the map in!

Comment: Hi, Thank for your explanation. I tried it but ı think i miss something.